# Display a specific result using foreach in Dictionary C#

Tags: c#-4.0

Problem that I'm unable to solve is that when I search a contact, if found than I need that contact to be the only output but it's displaying whole record. What should I do?

here is my code

```
namespace Telephone_Directory
{
    class Program
    {
        public bool info()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("ENTER THE NAME TO BE SEARCHED");

            Dictionary<string, uint> contact = new Dictionary<string, uint>();
            contact.Add("usman", 03453648729);
            contact.Add("Iqtiqa", 03159825052);
            contact.Add("Aamir", 03343315412);
            contact.Add("Ghous", 03323142783);
            var items = from pair in contact
                        orderby pair.Value ascending
                        select pair;
                      string chk = Console.ReadLine();
            if (contact.ContainsKey(chk))
            {


                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, uint> pair in contact)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
                } return true;
            }
            else
                return false;



        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         Program ob =new Program();
            bool a=ob.info();
            if (a == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your contact is found successfully");

            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Not found");
            Console.ReadLine();


    }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a very good way to do it.  Obtain the value directly without enumerating the entire dictionary first.  Use if (contact.ContainsKey(chk)) Console.WriteLine(contact[chk]);

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the Contact is available but you are iterating over the whole collection as an output. So you can completely remove the first query (var item = ...) because it does not have any effect because you are not using it anywhere.
I would propose accessing everything directly by the Dictionary Key like this

```
uint srchNumber;
contact.TryGetValue(chk, out srchNumber);
if (srchNumber != null)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", chk, srchNumber);
```

this will get you what you want.
But I would suggest to change the implementation because a Dictionary may be not optimal if you will have multiple items with the same name because it only allows you to have every key once. Instead I would suggest to use something like SortedList> or List<...>. Then you may query all possible results with a LINQ-Statement like

```
var results = from c in contact select c where c.key == chk
```

this will get you all Key-Value-Pairs belonging to a certain name.
But it is a matter of what you are trying to achieve.